# how to access google spreadsheet json file from s3 while using aws lambda with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-sheets

I am using `django` and deployed my application on `aws_lambda`. Everything worked fine until i wanted to save the content of the database in a `google spreadsheet`

The problem is how to access/get the `json.file` (that would normally be located in the same folder as where i am using it) now that i am using `aws_lambda` in production

## views.py

```
# how i would normally do it, locally

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("secret-json-file.json", scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

open_google_spreadsheet = gc.open('data').sheet1
```

but since i am using `aws_lambda` and i stored that json file on the main folder of my `aws s3` bucket.

I am trying something like this:

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=aws_bucket, Key="secret-json-file.json")

data = response["Body"].read()

# Google spreadsheet

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(data, scope)
```

I also tried this approach:

```
AWS_ID = aws_access_key_id
AWS_KEY = aws_secret_access_key
AWS_S3_BUCKET = aws_bucket

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_KEY) 

s3 = session.resource("s3")

my_s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(AWS_S3_BUCKET)

current_s3_file = []

for s3_file in my_s3_bucket.objects.all():
  if s3_file.key == "secret-json-file.json":
    current_s3_file.append(s3_file)

# Google spreadsheet

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(current_s3_file, scope)
```

Unfortunately both approaches are not successful since i am not able to run the command `zappa update production` anymore, it crash with `timeout`

Below is the ouput:

```
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 504 response code.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By "not successful" what you exactly mean? Is there an error showing up or you don't know the procedure of how to use a service account with Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @JoseVasquez I do, locally it works fine but when i try to update my zappa/aws lambda with `zappa update production` it `timeout` with the error update on the question above.

Answer (score 0):

import gspread

credentials = {
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "api-project-XXX",
"private_key_id": "2cd … ba4",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nNrDyLw … jINQh/9\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "473000000000-yoursisdifferent@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id": "473 … hd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
...
}

gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)

sh = gc.open("Example spreadsheet")

wks=sh.worksheet("Example worksheet")

I saw this solution in another publication

[Python - Make gspread.service_account take a python dictionary or string instead of file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869394/python-make-gspread-service-account-take-a-python-dictionary-or-string-instead)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).