# Python - Make gspread.service_account take a python dictionary or string instead of file name

Tags: python, gspread

I am currently using google sheets and is using the python library `gspread` to automate it. The first lines of my code would be to import the gspread library and login to a service account using the `service-account.json` file google console gives us.

```py
import gspread
account = gspread.service_account(filename='service-account.json')
```

but i want it to take a python dictionary instead of a file, so i wantsomething like this

```py
import gspread

creds = {'type': 'service_account', 'project_id': 'hidden', 'private_key_id': 'hidden', 'private_key': 'hidden', 'client_email': 'hidden', 'client_id': 'hidden', 'auth_uri': 'hidden', 'token_uri': 'hidden', 'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': 'hidden', 'client_x509_cert_url': 'hidden'}
#login to service account using these creditionals
```

i cant seem to find anything that does this, maybe due to my lack of searching skill.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the official document of gspread, I found the following sample script. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account)

#### Sample script:

```py
import gspread

credentials = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "api-project-XXX",
    "private_key_id": "2cd … ba4",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nNrDyLw … jINQh/9\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "473000000000-yoursisdifferent@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "473 … hd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ...
}

gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)

sh = gc.open("Example spreadsheet")

print(sh.sheet1.get('A1'))
```

- When I tested this script, `token_uri` was required to be included as follows. And, the values of `private_key`, `client_email` and `token_uri` were required to be used in my situation. But, I'm not sure whether my situation is the same with your situation. So, please test the above script in your situation.

  ```
    credentials = {
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nNrDyLw … jINQh/9\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "473000000000-yoursisdifferent@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [For Bots: Using Service Account](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account)