# How to use google app engine service account credentials for gspread without opening a web in python?

Tags: python, gspread

I tried to use gspread and deploy it in google app engine however it's returning FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.config/gspread/service_account.json'

how do I pass the google app engine's service account credentials that's being run in the background without using a json credential file?

Like I want gspread to use the default app service credentials. Is there a way to reference the credentials without stating the key in json format?

currently my code is as follows:

```
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
import math
import time

client = bigquery.Client(project="xxxxx")
gc = gspread.service_account()
```

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71869394 If this thread was the answer to your question, I will flag it as the duplicate question. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I think it's quite different, is there a way to auth without specifying the service account credentials? Like when we use the bigquery function, we do a bigquery.Client(project="xxxxx") and the rest is taken care of by the current service account. Is there a way to piggyback the current severice account credentials without stating it in the repo?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I think it's quite different`, I deeply apologize for this. I think that the reason for this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Not a problem, I will try to clarify so that it's easier to understand.